# Didn't understand relationship in FROM part of query call

Tags: apex, soql, query, relationships, childrelationship

I am trying to query the child record using the parent record id. I understand that we have to use the child relation name in the inner query to get the child records.

```
select id, (select id from child_relationshipname__r ) from parentobjt__c
```

In my case I use the same way to query but I get the error :

```
ERROR at Row:1:Column:28
Didn't understand relationship 'cyx__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

I am not sure why it is throwing error I doubled checked whether the child relationship name is correct.

```
select id, (select id from  namespc.Impacted_Products__r) from MC_Product_Complaint__c
```

Comment: Check the relationship name on the child object's lookup field, and also add the namespace if the object and field come from an installed managed package (e.g. namespace__relationshipname__r).

Comment: yes it is from the installed package. May be that the issue. let me check

Comment: I did add the name space but still get that error. attached some more details to question

Comment: Is MC__Product_Complaint__c a valid name?  I thought SF objects couldn't contain two underscores.  Also, is the namespace actually namespace or did you blank out exact namespace?

Comment: Sorry for that. Good catch. It is one underscore also I black out exact namespace to not to reveal the exact name

Comment: @SfdcBat It's namespace__relationshipname__r. No dots, just double underscores.

Comment: @sfdcfox - Got it now. Good learning. Thanks you very much! As usual you come to rescue me all the time :) Appreciate it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The syntax for a child relationship is:

```
[namespace__]relationship_name__r
```

So if the `relationship_name` is `Impacted_Products` and the namespace is MC, your sub-query would be:

```
(SELECT Id FROM MC__Impacted_Products__r)
```

It looks like you used `[namespace.]` instead of `[namespace__]`.

Note that you can *always* run this script to get the verbatim value you need to use in place of `MC__Impacted_Products__r` above:

```
for (ChildRelationship relation : SObjectType.Parent__c.getChildRelationships())
    if (relation.getChildSObject() == Child__c.sObjectType)
        system.debug(relation.getRelationshipName());
```

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Good to learn about the script to get verbatim value.

Comment: Thank you for script!

Comment: does the script go up the relationship too? for parents? or is there a way for that?

Comment: @GibralterTop For a parent relationship name you would just do `system.debug(Child__c.Parent__c.getDescribe().getRelationshipName()` with no need for looping.

Answer (score 4):

Where searching for the Child Relationship, you must use the Plural name of the Child Relationship object.  For instance, if searching for the child Contacts on an Account it would be:

```
SELECT Id, ( SELECT Id FROM Contacts ) FROM Account;
```

In your specific case, try cyxs__r (I am assuming the plural of the cyx object is cyxs).